# Calendar icon on iPhone in another App

Tags: iphone, calendar, icons

How can i add the Calendar icon with the date to another smart Calendar App that I just downloadet?

PS: I am Jailbroken and know how to use SSH!

Comment: I don't understand the question... Did you want the new app to use Apple's default calendar app's icon?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, and get it to work with showing the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this, but third party developers can't use dynamic icon for the home screen :(